# Creating express request object as if it came from another URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

There are many ways to mock requests using things like `supertest` and `nock` but what I'm looking to do is to be able to create fake request objects, as if the request was going to a different URL, that can be passed on to other processing functions.

```
app.get("/render", function(req, res) {
    // how do I do this?
    var fake = createFakeRequest("/bar/?baz=qux", req);

    // I want doStuff to believe the request came to /bar/?baz=qux
    doStuff(fake, function(err, result) {
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

I'm aware I could modify all of he variables such as `req.path`, `req.query`, `req.url` but I'm worried I may miss something, and it seems like someone out there must have already solved this problem.

The reason I need this behavior is that for any given URL in my CMS, there can be multiple drafts. Each draft will have different content elements, but those individual content elements may have logic based on the URL or query parameters. So even though the request came in as /render/?draft=1&url=/foo/bar/, I want the content element processors to believe the request came in to /foo/bar/ and be oblivious to the version system which actually handled the initial HTTP request.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure to understand but seems like url rewriting, so using a middleware could work

```
function urlRewrite(req, res, next){
    req.url ="...";
    next();
}
```

and so

```
app.use(urlRewrite);
```

Be sure to use it at the right place (depending on your server goal)
Cause we maybe need params before the rewrite... and if rewrite, you may need it after...

**EDIT**
In my framework:

```
server.before(extractPath);
server.before(urlParams);
server.before(pathParams);
server.get("/foo", route.foo);
```

So I could write

```
server.before(extractPath);
=> server.before( function(req, res, next){
    urlRewrite(req, res, function(){
        extractPath(req, res, next);
    }
});
server.before(urlParams);
server.before(pathParams);
server.get("/foo", route.foo);
```

If urlRewrite depends on urlParams, I could write

```
server.before(extractPath);
server.before(urlParams);
=> server.before( function(req, res, next){
    urlRewrite(req, res, function(){
        extractPath(req, res, function(){
            urlParams(req, res, next);
        });
    });
});
server.before(pathParams);
server.get("/foo", route.foo);
```

As I said, it depends on your framework

Comment: If I only alter `req.url` then `req.query.foo` will not be properly updated, unless there is magic I am unaware of in req.url which causes the other properties to be set when it is modified. Also I'm not looking for strict rewriting because I still want the /render handler to receive the request and return the response. I just want any functions which /render calls to be oblivious to alterations made to the request object.

Comment: Ok I've edited but you added your comment. I'm really sorry but I've no idea of what you try to achieve